# Desktop Couch Scratch Folder

Tags: ubuntu-one, firefox, sync

In the "Desktop Couch Scratch" folder, do I have to manually add the bookmarks I want saved, or does the system do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The system does it automatically.
- Adding things to that folder will accomplish nothing.